# Is there a version of script that plays nicely with vim?

Tags: terminal, scripting

`man script` says:

> Certain interactive commands, such as vi(1), create garbage in the type‐
>        script file.  Script works best with commands that do not manipulate the
>        screen, the results are meant to emulate a hardcopy terminal.

I tried this out, starting a script session and then launching vim, and there do appear to be control characters in the output. Replaying the typescript also left some control characters on my command line after `scriptreplay` had finished.

However, it did *mostly* work, even correctly capturing a vim session with a split window. The rogue control characters seem to be a slight annoyance rather than a fundamental issue. So is there a program similar to `script` that works without this annoyance?

Comment: I would say you were VERY lucky that script worked as we as it did for you. It's design intent was to capture console output.

Comment: @nelsonov If you replay on the same console type and with same size, the replay should produce the original output.

Answer (score 1):

short: probably not

long:

First, the comment in the `script` manual page is talking about the problem of taking that text and making a plain-text (no control characters) version which shows what you originally saw on the screen.  The `scriptreplay` tool is a work-around which doesn't try to make a plain-text file, but replay the text like a movie.

The `typescript` saved by `script` is hard to convert to a plain text file, because 
a full-screen text-editor such as vim uses *cursor-addressing*.  Rather than repaint the whole screen each time you make a change (which would in principle allow you to see a series of screens), vim moves the cursor around the screen to make changes.

If you do not make changes (including scrolling), you can certainly get a simple screen with few controls.  But the question is not asking about that special case.

If you were able to make vim use a terminal description which does not have cursor-addressing, then it "could" be forced to repaint (rather than move the cursor).  However, vim by default uses its [built-in](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27ttybuiltin%27) terminal descriptions, often ignoring the terminal database (see [code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/term.c#L1334)).  For example, in the terminal database, `dumb` has no cursor-addressing.  vim's version has cursor-addressing:

```
/* 
 * The most minimal terminal: only clear screen and cursor positioning 
 * Always included. 
 */
    {(int)KS_NAME,      "dumb"},
    {(int)KS_CL,        "\014"},
#ifdef TERMINFO
    {(int)KS_CM,        IF_EB("\033[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH",
                                                  ESC_STR "[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH")},
#else
    {(int)KS_CM,        IF_EB("\033[%i%d;%dH", ESC_STR "[%i%d;%dH")},
#endif
```

So you will have cursor-movement (and updates to the screen).

The control characters that you saw echoed to the terminal are a different feature.  [vim sends an escape sequence to the terminal](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/term.c#L4213) if it might be an xterm to ask what version it is (to turn on some optional features of vim).  That is a standard VT100 escape sequence ([Device Attributes **`DA`**](http://vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/chapter5.html#S5.5.2.26)), so lots of terminals (other than xterm) will respond, sending the characters to the computer, which leaves them on your command-line.

Comment: It's not hard to remove control characters, `less` even does it for you and has the `-R` switch to let only color escapes through. The issue I see with keeping them, especially with apps that manipulate the whole screen, is that you have to replay with the same terminal emulation and size... So it may be hard to replay a linux console from a GUI for example but you should have absolutely no issue replaying on a fully compatible terminal with same height and width. The binary data of the typescript will just replay all the control characters leading to what you saw initially.

Comment: `less` does one particular flavor, which happens to "work" for people using solely command-line prompt coloring.  For full-screen text, `less` is far less effective.